# Return type deduction substitution failure on clang, but not on g++

Tags: c++, g++, clang, c++14, variadic-templates

The following snippet does not compile with `clang`, but with `g++` (details below):

```
#include <utility>

struct S {
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T&& /*t*/) {}

    template<typename T0, typename T1, typename... Args>
    auto operator()(T0&& t0, T1&& /*t1*/, Args&&... args) ->
        decltype(operator()(std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {}
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv[]*/) {
    S()(1, 2);
    S()(1, 1.2, 1.2); // does not compile with clang
}
```

I.e. the variadic `operator()` should recurse until it reaches the base case.

When I compile this with `gcc 7.2.0` (`g++ -std=c++1y`), it compiles. But with `clang 3.8.0` (`clang++ -std=c++1y`), I obtain the following compilation failure:

```
main.cpp:15:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'S'
    S()(1, 1.2, 1.2); // does not compile with clang
    ^~~
main.cpp:8:10: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T0 = int, T1 = double, Args = <double>]: no matching member function for call to 'operator()'
    auto operator()(T0&& t0, T1&& /*t1*/, Args&&... args) ->
         ^
main.cpp:5:7: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 3 were provided
        void operator()(T&& /*t*/) {}
```

Is this a bug in one of the compilers or am I possibly hitting undefined behaviour somewhere?

Comment: [Can be reproduced with current clang](https://godbolt.org/g/DCE83U).

Comment: Can't remember the details, but I think that recursive `decltype` doesn't work properly due to annoying interactions between name lookup rules and template instantiation rules

Comment: You need to hide the fact that you call operator() of "this" (cast to a dependent type). That should do it

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: yeah, `decltype(std::declval<S>()(std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<Args>(args)...))` works. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: The *trailing-return-type* is part of the function declarator. The point of declaration of a name is immediately after its complete declarator.

Comment: @T.C gcc bug then?

Comment: @Barry yes, this looks like a GCC bug indeed.